# Are Complex Types in Entity Framework actually inheritance?

Tags: entity-framework

I am learning EF and came across the definition of a Complex Type:

```
"...used to define common properties among various entities."
```

This sounds exactly like factoring out shared state from a class and moving it into a base class.  My question is - is this inheritance from EF's perspective ?  I know that inheritance is supported in EF and that there are 3 ways to acheive it, but Complex Type sounds like it's separate from this.  Is it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not inheritance. ComplexType is more like a struct. It lumps a bunch of scalar properties together with value semantics.

You can do inheritance in the EF, yes, but nothing can inherit from a ComplexType.